# Formal usage of direct sum in a set of functions

Tags: functions, formal-languages, direct-sum

Define $f_i$ as functions indexed by $i\in I$.

Is it ok to say that $\bigoplus_{i\in I}f_i = f=(f_1,f_2,f_3,......)$?

I understand that the direct sum is often used in vector spaces or algebra structures. Is the usage here in functions common? I have never seen this kind of usage before, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct sums are used on structures, where it is a sum on structures that is also disjoint. Functions are maps not structures. However, if you are speaking about images or kernels of functions of a structure, you can inherit the direct sum (i.e. the image/kernel of a linear map is also a vector space, so you can apply direct sum to those). 
You see that this definition would cause some inconsistences in the language and should not be used. (There might be cases in category theory, however, were maps are considered as objects/structures. Then this definition would work fine)

I must admit that, that my original answer was not 100% correct. If you have maps between direct sums it is quite common to use the direct sums of maps.
For example:
Let $V_1,V_2,W$ be vector spaces and $f_1:V_1 \rightarrow W, f_2:V_2 \rightarrow W$ two linear maps. Then it is quite common to write $f_1 \oplus f_2 : V_1 \oplus V_2 \rightarrow W$ for the linear map that is inherited.

Comment: Is direct sum often used with operators?

Comment: On kernels/images of an operator, sure. But an operator is not a structure itself (there might be constructions considering it in category considering it like that), so the answer applies to operators, too. Maybe, you want to have a look on the tensor product :-)

Comment: Could you please give me an example for the usage your mentioned in the end?

Comment: Let $V_1 = \mathbb{R^2}, V_2 = \mathbb{R^2},W=\mathbb{R}$, $f_1$ be the projection to the first component, i.e. $f_1(x) = (1 0)x$, $f_2$ be the projection to the second component $f_2(x) = (0 1)x$. Then $(f_1\oplus f_2)(y) = (1 0 0 1)y$. More general, you can also us it with maps $g_1: V_1 \rightarrow W_1$, $g_2: V_1 \rightarrow W_2$, then in the finite dimensional by fixing bases, $g_1\oplus g_2$ gets a block matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}A_{1,1} & A_{1,2}\\A_{2,1} & A_{2,2}\end{matrix}\right)$ where $A_{1,1}$ is the matrix from $g_1$ and $A_{2,2}$ is the matrix from $g_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your $f$ is a *family* of functions, indexed by $i\in I$.  I suggest writing $f:=\bigl(f_i\bigr)_{i\in I}\ $. Note that we write $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ for the vector $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i{\bf e}_i$, and not $x=\oplus_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Comment: Is the direct sum notation you mentioned here not properly used or just not recommended?